# android: waking up the device

Tags: android, flags

```
public void Click(View view)
{

this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
         } 
    }, 30000); 

}
```

I want the screen to wake up after 30 sec (its set to 15 seconds timeout). But this doesnt work. What am i doing wrong? If theres a better way to do this, please provide a code sample, since im a newbie. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the following instead...

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
   ..screen will stay on during this section..
wl.release();
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html for more info.

You might have to play around with the flags to get the effect you are looking for.